# Inverse of a matrix having same elements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

How to find the inverse of a matrix whose all elements are same, for example suppose a 2×2 matrix whose elements are all same i.e., (say) 3,3,3,3). But we know that this matrix is singular and singular matrices do not possess inverse (this sounds contradictory), but i come to know that these types of matrices possesse inverse.
If these types of matrices have inverse than how to find them ?

Comment: "i come to know that these types of matrices possesse inverse." How did you come to know this? It is false, these matrices are not invertible except in the trivial $1\times1$ case.

Comment: You're right, it is contradictory. There is no inverse.

Comment: Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb F)\;n\geq 2$.
$A$ is invertible $\iff\;\exists A^{-1}\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I_n$.

$A\;\text{invertible/regular}\implies\operatorname{rank}(A)=n\;\&\det(A)\ne 0$ 

Let
$B=\begin{bmatrix}x&x&\ldots&x&x\\x&x&\ldots&x&x\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&x&x\\x&x&\ldots&x&x\end{bmatrix}$
We can $\text{annullate}$ every $\text{column(row)}$ by subtracting an arbitrary one from all. Then, $x\ne 0\in\mathbb F\implies\operatorname{rank}(B)=1\implies\det(B)=0\implies\nexists B^{-1}$  $$$$ This question should be closed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3113859/721644